# Error in RazorScriptManager - 0.6.1 of Nuget Gallery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, minify, nuget, nuget-package

I am using [RazorScriptManager - 0.6.1](http://www.nuget.org/List/Packages/RazorScriptManager) to minify my js and css files for my asp.net mvc 3 application.

When i use `AddJavaScript` method as:

```
@Script.AddJavaScript(localPath: "~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.min.js", siteWide: true)
@Script.AddJavaScript(localPath: "~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js", siteWide: true)
@Script.AddJavaScript(localPath: "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js", siteWide: true)
@Script.AddJavaScript(localPath: "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js", siteWide: true)
@Script.AddJavaScript(localPath: "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js", siteWide: true)
@Script.OutputJavaScript()
```

It shows js error for any script reference that comes after `jquery-1.6.min.js` reference. Below is the screenshot of the error:

[image: RazorScriptManager Error]
Please advice on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this might be a JavaScript-related issue, not a problem with the script manager.

The error itself appears to be in jquery.validate.min.js, which is being loaded after the reference to modernizr-1.7.min.js. I created an empty sample project referencing the same JavaScript files as you did (except with 1.6.1 instead of 1.6), and I did run into a conflict between script versions. I updated my sample project to use the latest versions, and I have no errors:

```
@Script.AddJavaScript(localPath: "~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js", siteWide: true)
@Script.AddJavaScript(localPath: "~/Scripts/modernizr-2.0.6-development-only.js", siteWide: true)
@Script.AddJavaScript(localPath: "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js", siteWide: true) //v1.8.1
@Script.AddJavaScript(localPath: "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js", siteWide: true)
@Script.AddJavaScript(localPath: "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js", siteWide: true)
```

Try updating all the JavaScript NuGet packages in your project and see if that solves your problem. If it doesn't, open an issue in the [project on GitHub](https://github.com/davecowart/RazorScriptManager) and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Also, in case you hadn't seen it, I wrote a blog post about how to use RazorScriptManager: http://davecowart.wordpress.com/2011/06/20/using-razorscriptmanager/. I also plan on writing one to explain the internal workings, so if you're interested in that check the blog later.

Comment: I am not sure anyone have faced an issue with RazorScriptManager package. When we use different master page(one before signin and the other after signin), it creates duplicate css classes and js scripts.(i.e. it refers that css and script file more than once). Did anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: Just for the record, this was fixed in the most recent version